# how to use "chkdsk" with JPowershell?

Tags: java, powershell, powershell-2.0

I would like to know how to get bad sectors of a hard disk drive through Java or Powershell.

I have been experiencing some problems when using the `chkdsk` command with the JPowershell library. i used to execute like

```
PowerShellResponse response = PowerShell.executeSingleCommand("chkdsk");
    return response.getCommandOutput();
```

and

```
PowerShellResponse response = PowerShell.executeCommand("chkdsk");
    return response.getCommandOutput();
```

I ran both in the administrative mode, but both of them return the output as

> The type of the file system is NTFS.

The problem in executing the `chkdsk` in powershell is that it takes sometime to get the information, and all after that only the data is shown.

Comment: Are you saying that the (only) problem is that `chkdsk` is taking too long?  Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I found the answer that JPowershell cannot be used for that instead I used the java runtime process because chkdsk command takes data dynamically. Therefore I had to execute and retrieve data manually